# Connection timed out on apache webserver

Tags: networking, apache-2.4, web-server, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem with reaching my server via a domain, I try to ping it and I get:

```
Pinging www.webuilder.co.uk [95.150.80.104] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 95.150.80.104: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 95.150.80.104: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 95.150.80.104: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 95.150.80.104: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 95.150.80.104:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\annon>ping webuilder.co.uk

Pinging webuilder.co.uk [95.150.80.56] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 95.150.80.56:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\annon>
```

Is the connection timed out because webuilder.co.uk cannot be accessed for some reason? I am using ubuntu server and apache for this, and everything seemed to work fine but today it just broke. If I ping from outside of my network I get request timed out for all of them. I am doing port forwarding so everything should be fine and it was yesturday

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you use that the www registry exists in your DNS server? if it does not, you should not be able to reach your web server without the www.

Edit: flushing DNS cache as I suggested solved the problem.

To flush DNS cache in OS X should be:

dscacheutil -flushcache

In Windows should be:

ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: well I cannot access the website either with or without www, and from external device I cannot ping it either so just trying to see what's wrong also if you notice www.webuilder.co.uk and webuilder.co.uk have different IP addresses for some weird reason and I don't know why

Comment: oh wait a second, if you can please try to access www.webuilder.co.uk or without www on your browser, because on my mobile it works fine..

Comment: Again, it seems like a DNS problem if they answer with different IP addresses. I would check your DNS server setup and make sure that a www registry exists and points to your EXACT web server. Besides that, check your web server configuration (virtualhost if apache).

Comment: Yep, works fine from here, both of them.

Comment: Another thing you can try, check your /etc/hosts file in that machine (the one you are using to ping), just in case there is an entry to www.webuilder.co.uk or webuilder.co.uk. If there is an entry for that, make sure that you need it. If you do, at least point to the same ip address both entries.

Comment: Ok I have pointed them both to the same ip address however I still get 2 different IP. it looks like it's a browser related problem rather than server because on microsoft edge it works fine. I have gone back to default settings on google chrome and still I get connection timed out

Comment: Really weird. I guess you are not using a proxy, right? Anyway, try to flush your DNS cache, just in case.

Comment: I am not using proxy, how do you flush DNS cache?

Comment: I found it, as you said flushing DNS cache worked, add this to the answer and I will mark it as accepted

Comment: @e9169, could you edit your answer to reflect the discussion in comments? The answer is it currently stands isn't all that helpful, but would be more so if you could explain a bit more about the DNS issues you felt would be resolved by flushing the local resolver cache.

Comment: Hi. I edited the answer to reflect that flushing DNS cache solved the issue.